# Objective C Char Array Issue

Tags: objective-c, arrays, char, symbols

Hey guys so I'm trying to learn objective c as an independent study for my school and one of my projects just to practice is making a calculator program where the user inputs a string of numbers and operators and the program breaks it apart and does the calculation. Right now I have the input and I'm trying to have it find the operators and put them all in an array so that it can sort them to find order of operations and use the indices to find the different terms; however, when I try to print out the array to see if its holding the chars, it outputs some weird symbols like the apple logo or an upside down question mark. I've made an SSCCE of my problem -- does anyone know whats going on?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {

    NSString *calculation;
    char str[50] = {0};
    int count = 0;

    NSLog(@"What would you like to calculate?");
    scanf("%s", str);
    calculation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

    for (int i = 0; i < [calculation length]; i++) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange (i, 1);
        if([[calculation substringWithRange: range] isEqualToString: @"*"] ||
           [[calculation substringWithRange: range] isEqualToString: @"/"])
            count++;
    }

    char operators[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < [calculation length]; j++) {
            NSRange range = NSMakeRange (j, 1);
            NSString *s = [s initWithString:[calculation substringWithRange: range]];
            if([s isEqualToString:@"*"]){
                operators[i] = '*';
                break;
            }
            if([s isEqualToString:@"/"]){
                operators[i] = '/';
                break;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%c", operators[i]);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `-characterAtIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about what is going on in your code. The "weird symbols" you are seeing are the un-initialized values in memory at your `operators[]` array.

To see the reason the char[] is left with garbage values look at this section of your code:

```
    ...
    NSString *s = [s initWithString:[calculation substringWithRange: range]];
    if([s isEqualToString:@"*"]){
        operators[i] = '*';
        break;
    }
    ...
```

You are sending `initWithString` to `s`. `s` is not yet allocated. This results in `s` being a `nil`. And since sending a message like `isEqualToString:` to a `nil` will *essentially* evaluate `NO` even when an `@"*"` is in that range your assignment to `operators[i]` will never happen.

Easy fix though, just replace the `s` assignment with this:

```
NSString *s = [calculation substringWithRange:range];
```

Comment: 'This results in s being a nil' - only under ARC.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I originally tried but for some reason it wasn't working. It's all good now.

Comment: @MattCooper I'm glad this helped. I generally try not to over-advise self described learning exercises, But, RichardRoss's advice to use `-characterAtIndex:` is good advice. It's more efficient, it doesn't create a new NSString each time, it simply returns a `unichar` which you can compare with `==`. And since composed character sets are unlikely to come up in a simple calculator(the main reason -`characterAtIndex:` is frowned upon) it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy for this. But: use stuff for what it is there for.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    char str[128];
    printf("Enter formula:\n");
    scanf("%s", str); // this is DAMN unsafe, btw

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];

    char *s = str;
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '*') {
            [arr addObject:@"*"];
        } else if (*s == '/') {
            [arr addObject:@"/"];
        }
        s++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does your code care about order of operations?  what  output will be for  this string @"3*6/2*4" ?

Comment: @SpaceDust The output will be `* / *`. But come on, why don't you **try it?**

Comment: @SpaceDust I didn't get what you mean by that.